# Issues implementing parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

I am trying to make my object Parcelable.  I have the following code for creating the object from the parcel as well as the function for writing to the parcel.  When trying to create the object from the parcel I get an error creating m_endTime and it says it cannot cast a String to a Long.  Not really too sure what is going on.

```
private RECTripFishery(Parcel in) {
    m_tripId = (Integer) in.readValue(null);
    m_fishery = (String) in.readValue(null);
    m_targetSpecies = (String) in.readValue(null);
    m_startTime = new Date((Long) in.readValue(null));
    if (in.readValue(null) == null){
        m_endTime = null;
    } else {
        m_endTime = new Date((Long) in.readValue(null));
    }
    m_startLatitude = (Double) in.readValue(null);
    m_startLongitude = (Double) in.readValue(null);
    m_endLatitude = (Double) in.readValue(null);
    m_endLongitude = (Double) in.readValue(null);
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeValue(Integer.valueOf(m_tripId));
    dest.writeValue(m_fishery);
    dest.writeValue(m_targetSpecies);
    dest.writeValue(Long.valueOf(m_startTime.getTime()));
    if (m_endTime == null) {
        dest.writeValue(null);
    } else {
        dest.writeValue(Long.valueOf(m_endTime.getTime()));
    }

    dest.writeValue(m_startLatitude);
    dest.writeValue(m_startLongitude);
    dest.writeValue(m_endLatitude);
    dest.writeValue(m_endLongitude);

    return;
}private RECTripFishery(Parcel in) {
    m_tripId = (Integer) in.readValue(null);
    m_fishery = (String) in.readValue(null);
    m_targetSpecies = (String) in.readValue(null);
    m_startTime = new Date((Long) in.readValue(null));
    if (in.readValue(null) == null){
        m_endTime = null;
    } else {
        m_endTime = new Date((Long) in.readValue(null));
    }
    m_startLatitude = (Double) in.readValue(null);
    m_startLongitude = (Double) in.readValue(null);
    m_endLatitude = (Double) in.readValue(null);
    m_endLongitude = (Double) in.readValue(null);
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeValue(Integer.valueOf(m_tripId));
    dest.writeValue(m_fishery);
    dest.writeValue(m_targetSpecies);
    dest.writeValue(Long.valueOf(m_startTime.getTime()));
    if (m_endTime == null) {
        dest.writeValue(null);
    } else {
        dest.writeValue(Long.valueOf(m_endTime.getTime()));
    }

    dest.writeValue(m_startLatitude);
    dest.writeValue(m_startLongitude);
    dest.writeValue(m_endLatitude);
    dest.writeValue(m_endLongitude);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

```
if (in.readValue(null) == null) {
        m_endTime = null;
} else {
        m_endTime = new Date((Long) in.readValue(null));
}
```

To:

```
Object val = in.readValue(null);

if (val == null) {
    m_endTime = null;
} else {
    m_endTime = new Date((Long) val);
}
```

**Edit:** Your problem is calling `readValue` twice.